# bridge/gateway for news (NNTP) to web forum

Tags: open-source, forum, gateway, nntp

I am looking for a *discussion forum* suitable for "geeks" and not so technically versed users alike.

For years we have been using a newsserver (NNTP) that the geeks are happy with (using Thunderbird or similar interface), however, the younger "facebook generation" would prefer something more like a through-the-web php-web-forum like discussion board. On the other hand, most geeks hate web forums and prefer mailing lists or nntp newsserver. Now, how to bring these different worlds together?

Ideally we thought of using a web forum (phpBB, MyBB or similar) for which a news-to-web-forum bridge exists? I know there is a mail2news gateway for mailman, but there does not seem to exist anything like a news2forum gateway? I searched the web, but none of the available web forums seem to have a NNTP integration. Open Source is the preferred option.

Comment: I had to custom build grepler.com as there was no bridge when I went looking for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there seem to be two options:

1. [FUDForum](http://fudforum.org) which has build-in support for [NNTP and mailing list synchronisation](http://cvs.prohost.org/index.php/Features#Mailing_List_and_NNTP_Integration) (my preferred choice)
2. [Syncom](http://wiki.piratenpartei.de/Syncom) (a plugin for MyBB written by the German Pirates' party). The source code for the plugin is at github, but it needs to be tidied up according to the German README at https://github.com/annando/Syncom and https://github.com/shirk/SynFU. Hence this seems to be  more of a "hacky" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but this sounds reasonable offering of nntp->forum offering with web fronted threading, quote collapsing, markdown support, unread message &  kill list support (limited, but configurable, not bad compromise), LDAP integration.

https://github.com/arkanis/nntp-forum

I wish they had a demo site.